# ImportError: No module named flask_restful

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy appengine flex python app but getting the following in Stackdriver log stderr  after deployment

```
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/my_service/entry_point.py", line 5, in <module>
    import flask_restful as restful
ImportError: No module named flask_restful
```

entry_point.py in line 5 has

```
import flask_restful as restful
```

And my requirement.txt has

```
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
gunicorn==19.7.1
```

Not sure why its still complaining about Flask-Restful

Comment: Apparently imports can be [case sensitive](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/), maybe check that out? Flask-RESTful in your requirements isn't all lowercase like most packages I've seen...

Comment: that was the problem. Not sure why it works when we use pip from command line.

Comment: Since that was the solution to the problem, may, @Sagasaki, post the good answer not as a comment but as an answer in order SoulMan be able to accept it and thus so help other SO users?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imports are [case sensitive](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/) on certain platforms, namely Linux (Windows and Mac may or may not care about case). The package Flask-RESTful isn't all lowercase like most packages (as per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) recommendation), so `import flask_restful as restful` will yield an import error unless the proper case is used.

Answer (score 22):

> ImportError: No module named flask_restful

Seems that you don't have **flask_restful** installed, to install run:

```
pip install flask-restful
```

in your **Terminal** and then run your app.

Documentation: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Might also be pip3 install flask-restful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... I was running my app using the "Play" button of Visual Studio Code and was stuck. Everything was already installed...
After a while I realized that I had to use the console of the IDE and start the program from there:

```
python App.py
```

I was running it under a **Virtual Environment**

Answer (score 1):

1. basically your project root directory is not matching with your python
   root directory for this specific (flask_restful) package,,
2. uninstall python application and reinstall it on window programs files,  you
   should install python in your window programs not separately

   i resolved it by this procedure (happy coding)