# 'python run.py' doesn't work in terminal(mac). flask_restful is installed. Gives the error: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful''

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, flask-restful

I have tried installing flask_restful via pip and it shows that all the requirements for it are already satisfied. But when I try to run the following command (python run.py) on my mac terminal, I get this error :

```
$ python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 17, in <module>
    app = create_app("config")
  File "run.py", line 7, in create_app
    from app import api_bp
  File "/Users/userName/Backend/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'
```

Comment: Which `python` are you using? You need to use the one in your `pip` environment - either by sourcing `activate` or by specifying the path, e.g. `venv/bin/python`

Comment: i am using python3 as a default. I tried with both, pip and pip3. it still shows all requirements are satisfied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named flask\_restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213822/importerror-no-module-named-flask-restful)

Comment: @Akif It didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this in your project instead of the current virtual environment?

- First install **pipenv** library
  `pip install pipenv`
- Go to the project directory.
- Next, activate the virtual environment
  `pipenv shell`
- Install all required python libraries.

  `pipenv install <library_name>`

  for example:
  `pipenv install flask`
  `pipenv install flask-restful`
  If requirements.txt file is available then
  `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`
- Run your code.
  `python run.py`

Comment: After running multiple commands in mac, now it is showing : can't open file 'run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Looks like I will have to restart my project as I've been stuck at it for long enough. But your answer was going pretty smoothly, so I think it might be able to help others who have the same problem. Do try this one if you have the same problem. Thanks a lot.