# Error in Colab when import autosklearn with IncorrectPackageVersionError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, automl

I'm trying to work with Autosklearn in Google Colab, for which I have done the following steps:

```py
    import sklearn
    print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
    The scikit-learn version is 0.24.2.
```

```py
import autosklearn.regression
IncorrectPackageVersionError: found 'scikit-learn' version 0.22.2.post1 but requires scikit-learn version >=0.24.0
```

Already scikit-learn version is 0.24.2. but WHY.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122292/python-run-py-doesnt-work-in-terminalmac-flask-restful-is-installed-gives/64123164#64123164 Please try this method